# Get link value in div

Tags: selector

I have a link in a div like this :

```
<div id="select-document-themes" class="dropdown">
                <a class="btn sort sort-down" href="#">All</a>
</div>
```

How do you select "All" with jQuery or Javascript please?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : -

```
var txt = $("#select-document-themes .btn").text()
```